# Jenkins pipeline fails to login to docker hub

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use pipeline to run a few things and when i started running my pipeline it failed to login to docker.

the weird thing is that i am able to login on the machine itself but when i run the pipeline is fails with this weird error:

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Front-end)
[Pipeline] node
Running on test-env in /var/www/test-env/workspace/client-e2e
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
Using the existing docker config file.Removing blacklisted property: auths$ docker login -u ***** -p ******** https://hub.docker.com/?namespace=******
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://hub.docker.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: docker login failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

I don't know why it performs a login when this image is publicly available for everyone.
can someone help me ?

this is the pipeline itself:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Front-end') {
            agent {
                docker { 
                    image 'node:8-alpine'
                    label "test-env"

                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a while i found out that it was as simple as doing this

```
pipeline {

    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Front-end') {
            agent {
                docker { 
                    image 'node:8-alpine'
                    registryUrl 'https://index.docker.io/v1/'
                    label "test-env"

                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this was aded: `registryUrl 'https://index.docker.io/v1/'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [Credentials Binding Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) in:

`steps {
                sh 'node --version'
}`

You can do:

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'mytoken', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
sh '''
  docker login -u '<your_user>' -p '<$TOKEN>' 
  node --version
'''
```

}

There is an example here:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41051